# Como executar um .php automaticamente, todos os dias, em um determinado horário?

Tags: php, apache

Alguém poderia me mostrar como criar uma regra (no Apache talvez) para que todos os dias, em um determinado horário, um arquivo `.php` seja executado. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional?

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-sao-e-como-usar-as-cron-jobs/
http://e-tinet.com/linux/agendar-script-php-crontab-no-linux/

Comment: Você usa uma hospedagem compartilhada (Hostgator, Godaddy)?

Comment: linux, nginx, php!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como você chama seu script no shell do Linux, pode usar o executável do PHP e chamar o script a partir do seu crontab.

Para executar “meu-script.php” a cada 1 hora faça o seguinte:

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/pedrodelfino/meu-script.php
```

Fonte: [http://e-tinet.com/](http://e-tinet.com/linux/agendar-script-php-crontab-no-linux/)